# Insert new custom row at the end of table while reloadData Xcode

Tags: ios, uitableview

Frankly, I know how to insert new custom row end of table without reloadData but now I want to know is how to insert new custom row end of UITable while reloadData.

Here is my piece of code to insert new custom row while reloadData. But new inserted row appeared at the top of table which is not what I want.

```
    CoachPadItem *newCoachPadItem = [[CoachPadItem alloc]init];
    newCoachPadItem.coachpadDescription = textView.text;
    newCoachPadItem.coachpadTagId = @"0";
    [_tagPointsArray addObject:newCoachPadItem];
    [_coachpadTableView reloadData];
```

**cellforrowatindexpath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Configure the cell...
    CoachPadPointCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CoachPadPointCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CoachPadPointCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CoachPadPointCell"];
    }

    counter += 1;

    cell.tagBtn.hidden = YES;
    cell.btnRemove.hidden = YES;

    cell.tagBtn.userInteractionEnabled = canEdit;
    [cell.tagBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(removeTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btnRemove addTarget:self action:@selector(removePad:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.btnRemove.tag = counter;
    cell.txtPoint.delegate = self;
    cell.txtPoint.tag = counter;
    cell.txtPoint.textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = 2;
    cell.tagBtn.tag = counter;
    cell.txtPoint.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    cell.txtPoint.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.txtPoint.userInteractionEnabled = canEdit;

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    CoachPadItem *curr = _tagPointsArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.txtPoint.text = cure.MyDesc;

    return cell;
}
```

Please help me how to put new row at the end of UITable?

Comment: Can you show the methods for loading cell `cellforrowatindexpath`?

Comment: @anhtu I've amended my question as adding cellforrowatindexpath. Thanks.

Comment: The new row should be inserted at the bottom. So weird.

Comment: @anhtu how to solve?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. This is not the solution but can you try `[_tagPointsArray insertObject: newCoachPadItem atIndex:0];` instead of `[_tagPointsArray addObject:newCoachPadItem];`. And what happen?

Comment: @anhtu 100% save my time. Can u post that coding as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's happen.

But, if `[_tagPointsArray addObject:newCoachPadItem];` cause **new inserted row appeared at the top of table which is not what I want**, you can try:

```
[_tagPointsArray insertObject: newCoachPadItem atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Inserted row itself correctly displayed at the end of UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

Trusting you are using `_tagPointsArray` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, iOS should automatically take care of new row insertion as I can see you have updated your model `_tagPointsArray` before `reloadData` call on your table view.

Just scroll down and see!

**EDIT:** After OP edited the post

Check these two lines:

```
CoachPadItem *curr = _tagPointsArray[indexPath.row];
cell.txtPoint.text = cure.MyDesc;
```

You are not consuming the fetched model object from the array. This must work if object was added at right position in the array. **Double check your model data positioning and also the above two lines I mentioned.**

Comment: But he said in the question "new inserted row appeared at the top of table which is not what I want."